# Strip function is not working. How to solve the problem?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to remove `\r\n` from the output in scrapy and I am using `strip()` function but it's not working. Instead it's giving me the result back with  `\r\n` without any error. Why it's not working and How could I solve this problem?

```
def Regional_category(self, response):
    items = response.meta['items']
    names = {'name1':'Site Description'}
    finder = {'finder1': '.site-descr::text}
    for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
        items[name] = response.css(find.strip()).extract()
        yield items
```

Comment: What is the  value of your `find` variable in `response.css(find.strip()).extract()`? Also strip removes values from start and end of string, are the `\r\n` present on those locations?

Comment: Whenever I print the result, it gives me output full of ```\r\n``` and I don't want. I have made a loop which is scraping some text from ```find``` from the site and giving me ```\r\n``` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
items[name] = response.css(find).extract().strip()
```

You were stripping the CSS selector, not the result.

If the result is a list of strings:

```
items[name] = list(map(str.strip, response.css(find).extract()))
```

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' ```

Comment: If the result is a list of strings: `items[name] = list(map(str.strip, response.css(find).extract()))`